# How to get text that has no node and attribute using xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

i'm trying to get a certain text in HTML using xpath.

The HTML is as below and as you see,

the "target text" which i want to get is in node p.

But "target text" doesn't have its node or attribute,

it is just presented alone in node p.

How can i get this?

Supplement : I'm using xpath in selenium. So, i couldn't use "text()" in xpath query

```
<p class="mean" lang="ko">
    <span class="word_class ">non-target text1 </span>
    <span class="mark">non-target text2 </span>
    target text 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target text` belongs to parent `p` node.
What you need to do here is:
Get the parent element text (it will include parent element text content and child element text contents).
Then remove child element text contents.
In case this is done with Selenium the code can be as following:

```py
parent_text = ""
all_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//p[@class='mean']")).text
child_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//*[@class='parent']//*"))
for child_element in child_elements:
    parent_text = all_text.replace(child_element.text, '')
print(parent_text)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion could be the solution i can use.

Comment: But i still wonder it can be possible to solve my problem by using only xpath query rather getting all the results and then replacing exception.

Comment: AFAIK this can not be done with single direct XPath expression only. At least not with xpath 1.0 since Selenium supports xpath 1.0 only

Answer (score 0):

Use `//p[@class = 'mean' and @lang = 'ko']/text()[normalize-space()]` to select any text node children of that `p` element that contain more than white space. Note that the text node contents begins after the closing `</span>` and ends before the closing `</p>` so its content with be e.g.

```
target text
```

If you want to remove leading and trailing white space you can use e.g. `normalize-space(//p[@class = 'mean' and @lang = 'ko']/text()[normalize-space()])`.

Comment: Thank you,  but i forgot to mention that i'm using xpath in selenium. So, it's hard to use 'text()' in xpath query